# Write a function that takes in a tree and returns the maximum sum of the values along any path in the tree

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I am looking at this coding question:

> Write a function that takes in a tree and returns the maximum sum of the values along any path in the tree. Recall that a path is from the tree's root to any leaf.

The following boilerplate code is provided with it:

> ```
> def tree(root_label, branches=[]):
>     for branch in branches:
>         assert is_tree(branch)
>     return [root_label] + list(branches)
>
> def label(tree):
>     return tree[0]
>
> def branches(tree):
>     return tree[1:]
>
> def is_tree(tree):
>     if type(tree) != list or len(tree) < 1:
>         return False
>     for branch in branches(tree):
>         if not is_tree(branch):
>             return False
>     return True
>
> def is_leaf(tree):
>     return not branches(tree)
>
> def max_path_sum(t):
>     """Return the maximum path sum of the tree.
>
>     >>> t = tree(1, [tree(5, [tree(1), tree(3)]), tree(10)])
>     >>> max_path_sum(t)
>     11
>     """
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
> ```

How can I define the `max_path_sum` function recursively using these pre-defined functions?

Comment: Please post the code on the post, instead of using an image.

Comment: Before solving, start with [ask] the question.

Comment: As you edit to include code, please follow the instructions you should see in a sidebar on how to put code in your post so that it looks like code.

Comment: I hope it got better. Thanks for your warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function recursively for the branches and add the current node's label to the maximum of those sub-results:

```
def max_path_sum(t):
    return label(t) + max(map(max_path_sum, branches(t)), default=0)
```

The default argument covers the case where `t` is a leaf, in which case the result will just be the node's label.

You could also call `is_leaf` to make the distinction, but it makes the code longer:

```
def max_path_sum(t):
    if is_leaf(t):
        return label(t)
    return label(t) + max(map(max_path_sum, branches(t)))
```

Comment: Sir, thank you very much, i am grateful to you.